# Problems with XML encoding in perl xml Lib

Tags: xml, regex, perl, utf-8

Replacing the Special Character using Perl  while i am doing this . I got this error . I just  try to merging the 2 xml file using XML::Lib.

parser error : Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding ! Bytes: 0xA3 0x32 0x33 0x6B
�23 to c�27 .

What is the issue and how to resolve this this

- I thought before going to XML Parser , I will replace those special character . But i am not aware of how to acheive this in perl ?  or is there any way to turn off this error and complete to merging with properl format
- i used th recover_silently ( XML LIb parser ), its removed all tags after the issue happened

Comment: Please provide the code that produces the error.

Comment: my $xml2 = $parser->parse_file("new.xml");

Comment: please edit the title for something more meaningful (problems with XML encoding, for instance)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some links that may be of interest (found by searching):

- http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=610066
- http://bytes.com/groups/perl/50726-libxml-utf8-input-not-proper-utf-8-indicate-encoding

Comment: Yes, the article from perlmonks gives the solution if the input document is properly encoded.

Answer (score 3):

Your input file isn't encoded in UTF-8. Convert it to UTF-8 before usage, see for instance this [excellent article.](http://plasmasturm.org/log/416/)

Answer (score 2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
```

I have just added this into to the XML File . Then works fine